# Longest path of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, recursive-algorithms, programming

Given a matrix

$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
1&2&3&4\\2&2&3&4\\3&2&3&4\\4&5&6&7
\end{pmatrix}
$$

We know that the length of the longest path that is increasing is $7$, i.e. $1,2,3,4,5,6,7$ assuming we can only move up, down, left, right with no wrapping.

I wanted to attempt to program how to find the length of the longest path and the elements that are in the longest path. From what I read online it seems most people used a depth search algorithm.

I was thinking if it was possible to find the length of the largest path using linear algebra or if there is a simpler way then using depth first search and dynamic programming.

This problem was found on: [here](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-increasing-path-in-a-matrix/description/)

Comment: There are very many approaches you can try. For example building a vector field which has high cost to go in "wrong directions" and is encouraged to have sources for low values and sinks for large values. Then you go with the flow of the found vector field and register the nodes you pass by.

Comment: I'd probably use A* search with manhattan metric as heuristic.

Comment: @mathreadler Do you have pseudocode I could work from. I am not much of a programmer but I know some about algorithms and data structures

Comment: @naslundx If you have any ideas please submit an answer, Ive been struggling on this for about 2 days now :/

Comment: I would minimize some regularized least squares problem on a 2D grid with discretized derivatives for source/sink.

Comment: But it's a bit too much for an answer really. More like an article or even a thesis, tbh...